Alternative to find(ismember) to find the position indices in an array
I'm having trouble to modify my code in an efficient way. I have a table of indices, say
table_of_indices=[1,2; 2,3; 3,1; 1,3; 11,8];
     

and take some specific elements in that table
E=[1,3;1,2];

Is there a smart way to find the positions of the elements of E in my table?
For now, I'm using
pos=find(ismember(table_of_indices, E, 'rows'));

but this is obviously super slow for a large table. Note that in my example, the code indeed returns 1 and 4.
I've found this question Faster alternatives to ismember in Matlab when index positions are needed? but I couldn't manage to translate that solution to my problem. Thanks for the help!

Here's another way: pos = find(any(all(table_of_indices==permute(E, [3 2 1]), 2), 3));  but I doubt it will be faster than using ismember

Believe it or not, but my computations went down from 2 minutes to 5 seconds. Thanks a lot!

Huh, that's surprising. Posting as an answer then

Here's another way:
pos = find(any(all(table_of_indices==permute(E, [3 2 1]), 2), 3));

I initially doubted this would be faster than the original approach using ismember, but the original poster @Spida says that, in their use case, this is indeed significantly faster.
